# How to test chrome extension in 2022

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing a chrome extension and I would like to know how to test it. I'm interested ideally in both unit and integration, but mostly integration tests. I've tried googling, but most of the solutions I found are either not good enough for the purpose or are using libraries which lost support. Also I'm new to javascript world, so if I would really appreciate a more detailed info. Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about what solutions you've found, and why they're not good enough. Otherwise, it's very likely that someone will write an answer, and you will say "I already know about this solution, but I don't want to use it because <insert reasons here>". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: One example is that in most cases you don't have access to the background script